# Default permissions of /dev on Mac OS X 10.5.*

Tags: macos, unix

Simple question. After a little bit of 'chmod' shenanigans, I have set the permissions for all pseudo ttys in /dev to a+rw which is somewhat open. Now that I have fixed the problem that I had, I want to revert my permissions back to the correct value.

Therefore, what are the correct permissions. Executing: sudo ls -la /dev/tty* should provide the result I am after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ uname -a
Darwin rhea 9.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.8.0: Wed Jul 15 16:55:01 PDT 2009; root:xnu-1228.15.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386

$ sudo ls -la /dev/tty* | head -n 30
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    2,   0 Aug 24 12:25 /dev/tty
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel   10,   2 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel   10,   0 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/tty.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,   0 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyp0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,   1 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyp1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,   2 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyp2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,   3 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyp3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,   4 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyp4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,   5 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyp5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,   6 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyp6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,   7 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyp7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,   8 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyp8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,   9 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyp9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,  10 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttypa
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,  11 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttypb
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,  12 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttypc
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,  13 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttypd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,  14 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttype
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,  15 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttypf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,  16 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyq0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,  17 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyq1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,  18 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyq2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,  19 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyq3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,  20 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyq4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,  21 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyq5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,  22 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyq6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,  23 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyq7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,  24 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyq8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,  25 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyq9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root   wheel    4,  26 Aug 18 20:00 /dev/ttyqa
```